# Will declaring a function generate any issues in the code

Tags: c++, c, header, prototype, declaration

In my project i have a Header file common.h which include many headers in it.Some of the files include Common.h and some other header which are already present in Common .h So In the Pre-Processing stage many functions get prototyped twice(Once from the Included header and other from Gui.h).I was wondering is this would cause any issue in long run.

Please suggest..Thanks in advance..

Comment: If they get prototyped twice for each translation unit then someone forgot their include-guard fenceposts.

Comment: `#ifndef A` `#define A` `#endif` or `#pragma once`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Headers should have [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) so that they are only processed once:

```
#ifndef SOME_UNIQUE_STRING
#define SOME_UNIQUE_STRING

// Everything else here

#endif
```

By "Everything" I mean "everything", starting with your `#include`s if any.

SOME_UNIQUE_STRING could be the name of the module as long as it is unlikely to coincide with another define somewhere else.

If you look in your library headers, you will notice they use include guards like this.

Comment: But i was wondering if there is any harm in prototyping twice..?

Comment: I can't imagine how there could be any *good* in it ;)  And yes, it can cause problems -- the most blatant being that you can't compile at all because of a  redefinition error.

Comment: You can have as many *declarations* of a function as you want, it will not cause any problems. You can have only one *definition* - unless the function is marked `inline`.

Comment: The *redefinition* error is more common with types (if you put a struct definition in and the header is processed twice, compilation will probably fail).  Using the guards is just a good habit to get into.  Fortunately, noticing the problem when they are missing, and fixing it, is usually pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

As Chemistpp suggested,    
     [#pragma once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)
is a good option to try, though it is non-standard.
Check out the advantages and disadvantages listed in the link.